# Histogram chart of categorical attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, chart

Using mmqgis I calculated the hub distance from source points to destinations but I would like to add histograms or similar diagrams to show the hub characteristics of the hub members `(count of Child by type, count of transport by type)`. I've tried adding histogram and piecharts but I'm not sure if I'm starting from the correct point or whether its the configuration of my diagram which is at fault.

- Layer Properties: Line (WKB type: "LineString")
- Feature Count:100

### Attribute Structure

```
RowID     HubName     Child     Transport
1         School1     Boy       Bike
2         School1     Girl      Car
3         School1     Boy       Car
4         School2     Boy       Walk
.         .           .         .
.         .           .         .
100       School6     Girl      Bike
```

### Desired Output

Beside `School1` I would have diagram showing the composition (CountOfBoy =x, CountOfGirl =y, Transport-Bike=z, Transport-Car=a). in chart form bdeside each Hub. I expect I'll be repeating the analysis with different destination points so I'd love to get an efficient way of accomplishing this without too much back and forth importing and exporting attributes and creating summary tables
[image]

Comment: My current thinking is to export the attribute table and create the summary stats offline befoe joining on HubName but is there a better way?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly was unsatisfactory with the histograms and piecharts that you attempted. Please explain more about this diagram you're looking for. Is it a chart? A table? Something else?

Comment: I wasn't able to generate any charts. I would like to provide summary stats about each hub based on the categorical attributes of the member rows and I'm not sure if my current layer is the best starting point or if I need to convert it first

Comment: This is an example of the attribute expression I'm using on my layer `count( "UniqueName" , group_by:="TransportMode")` where `UniqueName` and `TransportMode` are `string` columns

Comment: The attribute expression appears to make sense in terms of how you would go about producing the data to populate your chart. But I'm not sure how would accomplish this out-of-the-box with QGIS. Hopefully, somebody else can chime in regarding that.

Comment: Could it be the layer type I'm starting with thats the problem?